# Restrict possible values in one-to-many relationship

Tags: sql, postgresql

Let's say I have a table:

```
    main_type => Columns : id(pk), name
    sub_type => columns : id(pk), sub_type_name
```

One main type can have many `sub_type`

```
 eg. (main_type -> sub_type)  => a ->b, a->c, a -> d, b -> b, b-> c, c -> x, c->y
```

Now I want to have another table which will refer those two tables, but it should only allow the possible pairs from `main_type` and `sub_type` which I have defined as above.

So this table should be like:

```
another_table : columns => id,other_column,some_other_column,main_type,sub_type,desc
```

So, in another table if I try to enter values like:

```
1,'other value','some other value', 'a', 'y','description' =>
```

THis shouldn't be allowed as the pair `a->y` doesn't exist.

What could be the possibly better way to design the tables?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a combined foreign key, but you have to create a unique constraint for the referenced columns first:

```
ALTER TABLE type_table 
    ADD CONSTRAINT main_type_sub_type_unique_cnstr 
        UNIQUE(main_type, sub_tpye);

ALTER TABLE anther_table 
    ADD CONSTRAINT main_type_sub_type_fk 
        FOREIGN KEY (main_type, sub_type) REFERENCES type_table(main_type, sub_tpye);
```

The [docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/ddl-constraints.html#DDL-CONSTRAINTS-FK) doesn't refer to the unique constraint, but if it's missing you'll get an error like

> ERROR: there is no unique constraint matching given keys for referenced table "type_table"

Comment: You mean creating another table type_table which would have 2 columns which refers to the ids from main_type and sub_type. Next step to associate type_table to another_table right ?

Comment: Yes, I understood you like that. If you have a separate table for the subtypes, you could probably reference to the primary and foreign key to the man type of subtype table.

Answer (score 0):

First re-design your table **sub_type**  and **main_type** to one table i.e.TYpes_ALL
and make composite primary and foreign key relationship between them.

check code.

```
          Create Table TYpes_ALL
          ( Id SERIAL,
            main_type varchar(1)  ,
            sub_type varchar(1), 
            primary key (main_type,sub_type)
           )\\

         insert into TYpes_ALL (main_type,sub_type )values 
         ('a','b'),('a','c'),('a','d'),('b','b'),('b','c'),('c','x'),('c','y')\\


          Create table another_table 
          ( ID int , 
            other_column varchar(50),
            some_other_column varchar(50),
            main_type varchar(1)  ,
            sub_type varchar(1), 
            descp varchar(50),
            FOREIGN KEY (main_type,sub_type) REFERENCES TYpes_ALL(main_type,sub_type) 

           )\\

           insert into another_table values
           (1,'other value','some other value', 'a', 'y','description')
```

Now while insrting wrong record you will get error :

> 23503: insert or update on table "another_table" violates foreign key constraint "another_table_main_type_fkey"

Check Sample [Demo here](http://rextester.com/AEU82488)

Comment: I was thinking something like this only, i created another table with pairs refering to primary keys of main_type and sub_type and then having unique constraint on that table for pairs. Thanks for the help :)